# In the final episode of Legion, what exactly are they gonna look for?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, legion

In the final episode of Season 1 in [Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(TV_series)), the Shadow King leaves David's body and finds another host in Oliver, then Oliver (possesed) leaves the facility in a car and get away.

Later, we are shown Oliver possesed by the Shadow King driving the car, leaving. With the following dialog:

> Oliver: Where should we look first?
>
> Shadow King (Lenny): Some place warm.

Here's a screenshot of the scene:

[image: Legion]

Then later (post-credits scene), David says:

> They are headed south.

What exactly are they gonna look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Season 2 this is answered, they started looking for Farouk's body.

And "Someplace warm" refers to the desert where Farouk's body is located.

Answer (score 4):

What they're looking for isn't clear, and it might be nothing more than [an inside joke](http://www.denofgeek.com/uk/tv/legion/48357/legion-13-questions-we-have-after-the-season-1-finale):

> On a purely logistical note, we know that **Legion’s production is
>   moving from Vancouver to Los Angeles for season 2**, suggesting that
>   less secluded forests and more sunny city streets is what we’ll be
>   witnessing.
>
> [Hawley told Deadline](http://deadline.com/2017/03/legion-finale-spoilers-marvel-noah-hawley-dan-stevens-fargo-fx-1202054543/): “I think **part of the fun of the show as is
>   made obvious at the end of the first season is that they’re going on
>   the road.** So, the location is changing and I think that is another way
>   that we helped the show not settle into a sort of familiar routine of
>   standing sets and that sort of overly familiar sense of it’s the same
>   thing, week in and week out.”

Comment: Oh, I didn't know they were moving. I thought it was something related to the Shadow king seeking revenge against professor X, and professor X being in someplace warm. But it could be only an inside joke :)

Comment: I think this is half an answer.  They know they're shifting to LA - as the quote says.  So why not write that into the show to explain why season 2 is all deserts and hot places?  Half inside joke, half plot device.